# Takeover delay in Heartbeat HA cluster

Tags: linux, cluster, heartbeat, pacemaker

I have set up a heartbeat HA two node cluster. And both of server have same configuration of ha.cf

```
#cat /etc/ha.cf
logfile /var/log/ha-log
autojoin none
bcast eth1
warntime 20ms
deadtime 40ms
initdead 30
keepalive 5ms
node server1.com
node server2.com
```

I set keepalive and deadtime in milliseconds hoping failover will take place in less than second or deadtime value. But expected behaviour is not met.

With this configuration if I stop heartbeat in one server another server will take only after about 20 seconds(rough estimate by a stopwatch).

I was wondering is what heartbeat can only do or am I missing something?

Comment: It's been a long time I had my cluster running, so forgive me if my memory fails but.... shouldn't you also be running something like `pacemaker` besides heartbeat? I ask this because when you define the resources in `pacemaker` you also specify the time limit when the resource is transfered to the other node. Maybe this has something to do with your issue.